# How do I use AngularJS search filter on a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

If I have a list:

```
items = [
 {
  name: name1
  value: value1
 },
 {
  name: name2
  value: value2
 }
]
```

The following HTML work perfectly:

```
<input ng-model='search_field'/>
<span ng-repeat='item in items | search_field>[[item]]</span>
```

But how can I use this functionality if items is a dictionary like this:

```
items = {
   name1 : value1,
   name1 : value2
}
```

I'd like to use the dictionary representation because it's a lot easier for the operations I'm going to be performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('filters',[])
  .filter('objFilter', function($filter){

    return function(input, query){
      if(!query) return input;
      var result = [];

      angular.forEach(input, function(v,k){
          result.push(v);          
      });

      var refined = $filter('filter')(result,query);

      return refined;
    };
  });

 <span ng-repeat='item in items | objFilter:query'></span>
```

Comment: Yep! But in case of dictionary you should use second argument that angular.forEach() receives.